# How can i disable the grey out code in Vscode for string of some PNG data URI base64 images?

Tags: visual-studio-code, base64, png, uri

I have a "visual" problem in Visual Studio Code (1.42.1).
When i add a `data:image/png;base64` as a string and the string includes a sequence of `////////////////////////////////////////` (that seems common in png image) the string is greyout as you can see in the screenshot attached. It is annoying sometimes because in a dark theme I can hardly see the code itself.
Maybe a easy theme setting could help. But I can't find it.

Greyout code example:

[image]

Comment: What file type do you have? I can't reproduce in a Javascript file.

Comment: same js here. Thanks

Comment: everywhere i put four "////" the following code takes strike and grey out.. i check in textmate rules.. can't find anything

Comment: what if you disable all extensions?

Comment: Yes! that was an extension.. have to see yet which. Many thanks. I have lot of extensions so i never tried disabling all. i will follow when i find the extension that does that. Again thanks.

Comment: Ok was "Better Comments"

Comment: Ok for people having same problem: Just configure the extension for tag "//" in setting json and set it alone without option ("better-comments.tags": [
    {
      "tag": "//"
    }]  you need to reload vscode after that

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to "Better Comments" extension and its default tag setting for "//"

To solve the problem: Just configure the extension for tag "//" in setting json and set it alone without option

```
"better-comments.tags": [
{
  "tag": "//"
}
]
```

you need to reload Visual Code Studio after that